# HTML5 application cache issue - php session - logging out of applicaiton

Tags: php, session, cookies, html5-appcache

Testing an on-line application and the appcache is working, however, when logging out and then returning to the target php page the if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) to return the user to the log-in page is not working even though the session information is not present. The session has been destroyed, the user unset, and the cookie expired on logout. The same result trying to check the cookie status - if(!isset($_COOKIE['name'])). !isset is returning False even thought the cookie doesn't exist.

Remove manifest reference from the html tag and it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: cache - your "logged in" pages are kept in the browser's cache and will stay there until the browser tries to reload a page and your server generates a "not logged in" version of it.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Adding the manifest file to html page resulted in the html being added to the appcache even though it didn't reside in the manifest. The work-around was to load inject an html page into the main page and load the manifest in that manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest reference in the html tag  adds that page to the appcache even though it's not listed in the manifest file. Viewing chrome://appcache-internals/ in the browser displays the appcache and the html page as the master item.

Chrome and Safari appear to be ignoring no-chache no-store http headers when using appcache. When injecting an iframe to load a separate page containing the manifest, the main page elements weren't being retrieved from Chrome's cache.

The solution was to check the cookie or sessionstorage state in javascript to ensure the user wasn't directed to the cached page when logging back in.